# Router requirements for VLANS

Tags: switch, router, vlan

I want to set up a ["router on stick"](http://www.firewall.cx/cisco-technical-knowledgebase/cisco-routers/336-cisco-router-8021q-router-stick.html) configuration in my home network. I have a very basic wireless router (DLink DIR-836L ) that connects to the cable modem.

Can I connect this router to a managed switch (CISCO 2950) and create VLANS?. From my research it appears that routers need to support certain protocols (VTP, dotq11) to work with VLANS, is that true?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your VLANS to talk to each other and the Internet then you need something that can route between them.

There are a few ways this can be set up.

1. have a separate interface on the router for each VLAN. In this case you would need a router that can support multiple independent lan-side interfaces.
2. have the router do 802.1q. In this case your router would need to support 802.1q virtual interfaces.
3. have a layer 3 capable switch handle the routing between the VLANs and use the router for external routing only. The router would then have a static route configured to tell it to send all traffic for other vlans to the switch while the L3 switch would have it's default gateway pointing at the router..

Looking at the manual for your router I belive options 1 and 2 are not possible with your current router but option 3 looks doable.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct you need to have support of dot1q on Dlink to be able implement router on stick. Ideal solution would be intervlan routing on switch but yours 2950 is layer 2 device, router on the stick isn't preffered solution.